# Google Sheets Filter works, but not as an ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, max, vlookup

So I'm trying to use a Filter function in Google Sheets to return the value from one column based on locating a maximum value in another.

This is for Google search traffic which for several reasons needs to be digested in Sheets before anyone recommends any tools to use.

I have 3 columns, which are URL, search query, and clicks (A, B and C respectively).

I'm trying to use the filter to show in another list of all unique URLs which we'll call URLs, which query led to that page with the highest number of clicks.

My formula is:

```
`=FILTER(ColB,ColA=URL,ColC=MAXIFS(ColC,ColA,URL))`
```

It works exactly as required, until I try and use it as an array formula in the heading of my sheet, which is a necessity. With every other formula I've done this with I just expand the "URL" cell reference to be the whole column, nest it in an array formula and it's all good.

Can anyone help me put this into an array? I can't share the sheet for security reasons, but may be able to knock up a basic version of the problem if needed.

I've tried using a few different formula ideas, vlookups don't work for this, I can't get an index to do the right thing either. Been digging through forums for hours to find a solution and thought I had it with this Filter idea, til the array didn't work.

Comment: Here's a copied sheet that demonstrates the problem. In one report tab it works when in the cell, in the other I've moved it into an array formula and it's busted.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EmXAwOFfaX09H63TjBlgoITDMh74zl_96v-f-wg66W0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=vstack(<header>,
        map(URL,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,ifna(filter(ColB,ColA=Σ,ColC=maxifs(ColC,ColA,Σ))))))
       )
```

Comment: Thanks for this - what should I use for the URL? And does the header need to be in quotation marks or just within the angle brackets?

Comment: formula added to your test sheet

Comment: You're a hero, thank you!

Comment: replace this part `ifna(filter(` in the formula to `ifna(+filter(`

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. More help required I'm afraid.. Have you any idea why there might be a blank cell returned, with no value, even when there is definitely a match to the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

FILTER is not the appropriate function of this application.  Try this:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A2:C,3,0),9^9,2,1,1)
```

Comment: Are you able to talk me through what this all means so I can tweak to my cell ranges etc as required?

Comment: @LiamThomas i added the formula to your sample sheet in the tab called mk_Help.

Did i misunderstand where your data is? It seems to be giving the correct output.

Comment: to be clear I was saying to not bother at all with UNIQUE() or FILTER() or ARRAYFORMULA()